# is it possible to add an event listener to the options in a select list so that the First option is clickable without a placeholder?

Tags: javascript, html

How do I 'Pass' the first two cases WITHOUT adding some extraneous 'make a selection' option?

The select list should behave as if there was a 'selected' option; the dropdown opens but no selection is yet made.

I don't think it's possible.

The two cases are in the HTML portion. One of them is commented out.

@ Randy I don't yet understand the event constructor enough and I'm currently researching it.  Your solution passes one of the cases but not the other.

```js
(function() {

  const output1 = document.getElementById('output1')
  const output2 = document.getElementById('output2')
  const options = document.querySelectorAll('option')
  const optionsArray = []
  let arrayDotFrom = Array.from(options)
  const selectedArray = []
  const select = document.querySelector('select');
 

 /*
  options.forEach((option, i) => {
    if (option.value !== '') {
      optionsArray.push(option.value)
      output2.innerHTML = `optionsArray: ${optionsArray}`
      //console.log(option.value)
    } else {
      output2.innerHTML = `optionsArray: ${optionsArray}`
    }
  })
  */
  output1.innerHTML = `selectedArray: ${selectedArray}`
  output2.innerHTML = `Result:`

  select.addEventListener('change', addToArray = (e) => {
   

    // if (e.target.value === '') {
    // alert('No Selection made. Select an Option.')
    if (selectedArray.length === 0 && e.target.value === 'value1') {
      selectedArray.push(e.target.value)
      output1.innerHTML = `selectedArray: ${selectedArray}`
      output2.innerHTML = `Result: ${e.target.value}`
      select.removeEventListener('change', addToArray)
    } else if (selectedArray.length === 0 && e.target.value !== 'select') {
      selectedArray.push(e.target.value)
      output1.innerHTML = `selectedArray: ${selectedArray}`
      output2.innerHTML = `Result: ${e.target.value}`
      select.removeEventListener('change', addToArray)
    } else {
      selectedArray.shift()
      selectedArray.push(e.target.value)
      output1.innerHTML = `selectedArray: ${selectedArray}`
      output2.innerHTML = `Result: ${e.target.value}`
      select.removeEventListener('change', addToArray)
    }
      select.addEventListener('mousedown', addToArray);
      select.removeEventListener('mousedown', addToArray)
  }, false)
})();
```

```css
* {
  font: 1.1rem system-ui;
}

span {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
}

#bottom {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
}

#top {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
}

select {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  /* for multiple */
  /*  height: 125px; */
}
```

```html
<!--     ---      'There can be only one'.    ---    -->
<div id='selectList'>
  <label for='select'>Select:</label>

  <!-- <select multiple> -->

  <select name='select'> -->

<!-- case one -->
    <!-- <option value='Fail1'>Fail</option>
    <option value='Pass1'>Pass</option> -->
    
<!-- case two -->
     <option value='Pass2'>Pass</option> 
     <option value='Fail2'>Fail</option> 

<!-- case three -->
    <!-- <option value='select' selected>Avoidable?</option>-->
    
     <option value='Fail3'>Pass</option> 
     <option value='Fail3'>Fail</option> -->
  </select>
</div>

<div id='bottom'>
  <p id='output1'></p>
  <p id='output2'></p>

</div>
```

Comment: What exactly would you like to happen? For the first option in the `<select>` list to be clickable without an explicit placeholder option? Like the first option being "Choose an option" or an empty first option?

Comment: The short answer is Yes.

Comment: If the select type is multiple, the first option is selectable.

Comment: The select drop down in the example only allows one selection at a time. See https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp for how to do more than one.

Comment: if its not <select multiple> right.  and that is what i'd like a plain old <select> for just one option

Comment: How do i make the FIRST option clickable?

Comment: without first clicking one of the other options

Comment: and without a placeholder option.

Comment: i mentioned 'multiple' merely to draw attention to the fact that, when it's a multiple select, the first option is immediately clickable.

Comment: I've updated my answer to meet the needs stated in your comment.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have to be clickable, it just needs to be `selected` - add the `selected` attribute and it is set. [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option#attributes)

UPDATE: I changed the answer, but still don't understand the use case you stated in your comment. If you are always going to select the first option in the select, you have no choice as you have described this in your comment, then I don't understand why you don't just jam it in the array to begin with and then move on to the other choices.

As it stands, this new code allows you to place the first element in the array with a "single click" as you describe. Then, randomly select any others from the list.

```js
const select = document.querySelector('select');
select.addEventListener('change', addMe);
select.addEventListener('mouseup', changeMe);
let chosen = [];

function changeMe(e) {
  select.removeEventListener('mouseup', changeMe);
  select.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
}

function addMe(e) {
  chosen.push(e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].value);
  console.log(chosen);
}
```

```html
<select name='select'>
  <option value='value1' selected>value1</option>
  <option value='value2'>value2</option>
  <option value='value3'>value3</option>
  <option value='value4'>value4</option>
  <option value='value5'>value5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Sorry. I must not be clear enough. I want to be able to click the first option in the select list and populate the array with one click. run my snippet and click the second option. You will see your selection immediately in the array printed to the screen. REload the snippet and try to click the first option and you will see that clicking it Does NOT populate the array

Comment: and Thank You guys any input is appreciated.

Comment: Your logic here isn't very clear here buddy so a user selects value='value1 from the drop down menu. What's supposed to happen next? maybe add it to your question in numbered steps. Or link to an example of this code in action somewhere else.

Comment: @CliveAtkins - I'm not sure your comment is directed at my answer or the OP's question. Can you clarify your point please?

Comment: @Randy Casburn At the guys question you answered it the same way I would have. He said it wasn't what he wanted so i'm asking him to break it down so we can understand and help.

Comment: got it - might be better to put that comment with the question. And I agree with you!

Comment: @ Randy Casburn apologies sir was commenting to him on the above question. I've just scrolled down too far and highjacked your answer by accident.

Comment: @ Randy Casburn Thank You! I never thought to use TWO event listeners. I ended up with a 'mousedown' and a 'change' calling the same function.

Comment: Again apologies for being unclear. Your expertise is appreciated.

Comment: imagine a use case where the user only gets to choose ONE of the five options and ..maybe it isnt number one

Comment: then immediately the next page loads with the same form and the user is again allowed only one choice.. maybe they do want to choose option one... maybe not

Comment: @ Randy Casburn Thank You *again*for the polite nudge to clarify the use case

Comment: Im still trying to get it happing without pushing to the array before the user clicks.. but i gave you the vote for the Double Listener Changeup. Thats a nice!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply initialize your selectetArray with the first options's value:

```
const selectedArray = [ arrayDotFrom[0].value ]
```

So your JS will look like this:

```
(function() {
    const output1 = document.getElementById('output1');
    const output2 = document.getElementById('output2');
    const output3 = document.getElementById('output3');
    const output4 = document.getElementById('output4');
    const options = document.querySelectorAll('option');
    const optionsArray = [];
    let arrayDotFrom = Array.from(options);
    const selectedArray = [ arrayDotFrom[0].value ];

    const select = document.querySelector('select');
    options.forEach((option, i) => {
        if (option.value !== '') {
            optionsArray.push(option.value);
            output2.innerHTML = `optionsArray: ${optionsArray}`;
        } else {
            output2.innerHTML = `optionsArray: ${optionsArray}`;
        }
    });
    output1.innerHTML = `options.length: ${options.length}`;
    output2.innerHTML = `optionsArray: ${optionsArray}`;
    output3.innerHTML = `Object.keys(options): ${Object.keys(options)}`;
    output4.innerHTML = `selectedArray: ${selectedArray}`;
    select.addEventListener(
        'change',
        (addToArray = (e) => {
            selected = e.target.value;
            if (selectedArray.length === 0 && e.target.value === 'value1') {
                selectedArray.push(e.target.value);
                output4.innerHTML = `selectedArray: ${selectedArray}`;
            } else if (selectedArray.length === 0 && e.target.value !== 'select') {
                selectedArray.push(e.target.value);
                output4.innerHTML = `selectedArray: ${selectedArray}`;
            } else {
                selectedArray.shift();
                selectedArray.push(e.target.value);
                output4.innerHTML = `selectedArray: ${selectedArray}`;
            }
        }),
        false
    );
})();
```

A better user experience is to set your first option to some text to explain to your user the action intended, something like this (and keep your JS the way it was):

```
  <option value='value1' selected>Choose A Value</option>
  <option value='value2'>value1</option>
  <option value='value3'>value2</option>
  <option value='value4'>value3</option>
  <option value='value5'>value4</option>
```

Comment: Thank you Sedki! This question definitely became more and more of an experiment.  then turned to pure challenge to make option one selectable without the typical placeholder as a first choice. I learn something new with EVERY interaction on SO. Thanks again

Comment: is there a way we could do this withOut pushing the selection to the array until the user clicks?

Answer (score 0):

TrentHarlem, to answer your question in the comment, if I understood you well:
You can initialize some default values in your html so that the UI don't get distorted ( display none when page loads, then text appear when the user select an option ), and get rid of the array all together and instead include it inside your event listener to make sure it's values get updated every time the selection change. Something like this:

```
  <div id='selectList'>
    <label for='select'>Select:</label>
    <select name='select' autofocus='false'> -->
      <option value='value0' selected>Choose A Value</option>
      <option value='value1'>value1</option>
      <option value='value2'>value2</option>
      <option value='value3'>value3</option>
      <option value='value4'>value4</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div id='bottom'>
    <p id='output1'></p>
    <p id='output2'>optionsArray:</p>
    <p id='output3'></p>
    <p id='output4'>selectedArray:</p>
  </div>
```

And your JS (assuming you want to keep previous choices in the selected array:

```
(function() {
    const output1 = document.getElementById('output1');
    const output2 = document.getElementById('output2');
    const output3 = document.getElementById('output3');
    const output4 = document.getElementById('output4');
    const options = document.querySelectorAll('option');
    const optionsArray = [];
    const select = document.querySelector('select');
    select.addEventListener(
        'change',
        (addToArray = (e) => {
            output4.innerHTML = `selectedArray: ${e.target.value}`;
            optionsArray.push(e.target.value);
            output2.innerHTML = `optionsArray: ${optionsArray}`;
        }),
        false
    );
    output1.innerHTML = `options.length: ${options.length}`;
    output3.innerHTML = `Object.keys(options): ${Object.keys(options)}`;
    output4.innerHTML = `selectedArray: ${selectedArray}`;
})();
```

Comment: you assume correctly, the array should contain the users last selected choice from each select list (thats what the shift was for for  in the original question). at first i was strongly against the "choose an option' placeholder type first option. but its being so troublesome to remove that i may decide to workaround it. Also the id='bottom' div was me putting a console.logon the html to see what was happening with the arrays. ultimately it'll be a picture based on the previous choice and a new list of options. going thru a short story..